# Menu corrupt on IE7 - wordpress website

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem on a website page on : http://ilanerez.co.il/?p=58

Where the menu is corrupt(IE7): [image]
While it suppose to look like this (IE8): [image]

Well I guess it's a css issue.
The div is top_sidebar_page.
Can you help me find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you float items in IE7, then their closest parent must has a width property, otherwise they will float out of the window like it happend already.

Try giving to the ul and the div nav_menu-4 above it a width property and it suppose to work.